# Get Event Listener Element Instead Of Child In VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to get the element to which I have attached an event listener in the following code.

```
<div class="navigation-link" id="home" @click="click($event)">
  <button class="navigation-link-inner btn-large transparent z-depth-0">
    <i class="material-icons left">contact_mail</i>Home
  </button>
</div>
<div class="navigation-link" id="cms" @click="click($event)">
  <button class="navigation-link-inner btn-large transparent z-depth-0">
    <i class="material-icons left">contact_mail</i>CMS
  </button>
</div>
<div class="navigation-link" id="contact" @click="click($event)">
  <button class="navigation-link-inner btn-large transparent z-depth-0">
    <i class="material-icons left">contact_mail</i>Contact
  </button>
</div>
```

But when I click on the links, I am getting these elements depending on exact click location:

```
<i class="material-icons left">contact_mail</i>Home
```

```
<button class="navigation-link-inner btn-large transparent z-depth-0">
  <i class="material-icons left">contact_mail</i>Home
</button>
```

```
<div class="navigation-link" id="home">
  <button class="navigation-link-inner btn-large transparent z-depth-0">
    <i class="material-icons left">contact_mail</i>Home
  </button>
</div>
```

I only want to get this element

```
<div class="navigation-link" id="home">
  <button class="navigation-link-inner btn-large transparent z-depth-0">
    <i class="material-icons left">contact_mail</i>Home
  </button>
</div>
```

i.e the parent element that to which I have attached event listener. How can I get this?
Is there a short way to do this by attaching only one one event listener to parent and not on every link?

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this to show the issue.

Comment: yes, there you go https://playcode.io/vue_events

Comment: I want the parent div, i.e .navigation-link div, no matter I click on icon, button or itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to reference the element that the listener is attached to, you should use [`evt.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) instead of [`evt.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).

Comment: Thanks bro, it worked. Is there a better way to do this? Like if I have many links, then I have to attach listener on every link, can I put them in some external parent <div> and then attach the listener on that div to capture all clicks on these links?

Comment: Can you explain your main purpose/usage in a scenario? Like why do you want to make one listener for several links when you are interested in detecting the click of each seperately?